# How can I ensure uniqueness on a django model depending on the value?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

The title may be slightly misleading, I essentially want to know how to ensure uniqueness on 1 type of attribute, but not on others. If I have a model 'MyModel' that has a related model called 'Settings', which sets certain attributes for MyModel, how do I ensure that there is only one default settings object?

What is the best way to make sure that only one settings object is the default? I can put that 'default' and 'related_model' are unique_together, but this only allows for one non-default settings object as well. I'd like to get to the point where I can only have one default settings object, but no limit on non-default ones.

```
MyModel
attribute1 = x
...
```

```
Settings
related_model = MyModel
default = boolean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, I don't think you can set this up in DB level. But you can do it in Settings Model. Lets say your `MyModel` Model has relation in `Settings` Model. Like this:

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(Settings, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="attributes")
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then in your `Settings` model, you can add a constrain like this in save method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Settings(...):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.mymodel.attributes.all()
        if self.pk:
            query = query.exclude(pk=self.pk)

        if self.default == True:
           if query.filter(default=True).exists():
               raise ValidationError("Already a default value exists")
        return super(Attribute, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```